# Is there a way in Plotly panel for Grafana to plot a polygon given vertex coordinates?

Tags: plotly, grafana

I'm using Grafana in order to visualize data from a Influx database and I have to plot the position of a rectangle in a 3D plot given the coordinates of the four vertex points. Is there a way to do that with a Plotly panel? If not is there a way to connect with lines the markers from different traces in order to manually build the rectangle? Do you reccomend e to use a different plugin? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the layout.shapes:

[image: rectangles on Plotly plot]

See: https://plotly.com/javascript/shapes/